# Get elRTE Content Via POST Method PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, elrte

I am trying to store a content of elRTE into the database using PHP,

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // elRTE with elFinder on a textarea
        $().ready(function() {
            var opts = {
                cssClass : 'el-rte',

            $('#editor').elrte(opts);
    })
    </script>



    <div id="finder"></div>
  <form name="feedback" method="post">
        <textarea id="editor" name="acontent" cols="50" rows="4"><?=$abt_content?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="updabt" value="Submit"></td></tr>
  </form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['updabt']))
    {
        extract($_POST);
        $q1=mysql_query(...);
        if($q1==true)
        {...}
        else
        {...}
    }
?>
```

But I always get error "Undefined variable acontent"..

Any solution on this??

Answer (score 1):

```
  <form name="feedback" method="post">
         <div id="finder"></div>
        <textarea id="editor" name="acontent" cols="50" rows="4"><?=$abt_content?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="updabt" value="Submit"></td></tr>
  </form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['updabt']))
    {
        extract($_POST);
        $q1=mysql_query(...);
        if($q1==true)
        {...}
        else
        {...}
    }
?>
```

Note: for editer you have to use div's id for POST as

```
$_POST['finder'];
```